# How to add the "user role field" in View showing users

Tags: 7, views, users

I created a view showing users. Then I have a list of users. I need to add a field to show the user role. I clicked **add field** but I don't see this field. Do I need to add a relationship to have this field available?

**Update:** I have Aggregation enabled.

[image]

Comment: Roles dissapear cuz of aggreagation, if u read the description on views u will see `If enabled, some fields may become unavailable.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to add 2 field into your view `User uid`(exclude from display) and `Custom text`, next go to your `template.php` and do next

```
//implement hook_preprocess_views_view_fields
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
    $view = $vars['view'];
    $fields = $vars['fields'];

    if ($view->name == 'usr1') { // change on your view name
        $results = $view->result;
        $roles = array();
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            $user = user_load($row->uid);
            $roles = implode(', ',$user->roles ); //get all user roles
            //check if user name from field equal to current user in array
            if ($fields['name']->raw === $row->users_name) { 
                $fields['nothing']->content = $roles;//put that roles to custom text field
            }
        }
    }
}
```

THIS CODE NEED IMPROVEMENTS, cuz it iteracts on every field of your view, so you can work on this :D.

Comment: thanks, but I don't get it. Do you mind to elaborate on this, please

Comment: ok wait a bit, gonna post example here

Comment: I can't get it working, no errors, just not working.

Comment: are you sure u use proper view name `if ($view->name == 'usr1') {` and use `dpm` for debug to see what is wrong, maybe some names may differ from mine,  like this -> `$fields['name']` or `$field['nothing']`

Answer (score 2):

Try to **disable Aggreegation, enable the Role field and then enable again the Aggreegation**.

Notice that the Role field is a multi-value one (Roles is a list).

So if I understand well you should better use a module like https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator.

Answer (score 0):

There should be User:Roles available in field list.

Comment: I agree. But look at the capture I uploaded at the bottom of my question