# How to display Commerce Order Owner role in Views fields?

Tags: 7, views, commerce

Using Drupal 7.58 and Views 3.18

I am simply trying to display Commerce Order Owner role on a View. Using the Commerce Order:Owner relationship, I have access to a large set of user fields and properties... except the User role? Did I miss anything here?

EDIT : I am using Aggregation on my View (if you want to replicate this issue)

EDIT#2 : interesting workaround [here](https://www.zyxware.com/articles/3333/solved-drupal-views-user-roles-disappeared-after-enabling-use-aggregation), simply add the user role field before activate the aggregation... Still, I could not manage to build a chart and only a list of roles counted per user, using Table with aggregation options display

[image]

Related question : [How to add the "user role field" in View showing users](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53226/how-to-add-the-user-role-field-in-view-showing-users)

Answer (score 0):

No clue why it's not showing. The Views module defines a "User: Roles" field, and I see that just fine in my own development environment for a View joining to Users via the "Commerce Order: Owner" relationship.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your time on this test. I will try again this week and let you know if I find the answer to that mystery.

Comment: I may have found something interesting. Actually, the User: roles field is no more available if you use aggregation. I need this to show simple stats for my client (x orders from people with role Public customer and y orders from people with role Private customer, for example). Is it a bug or is it working as planned?

Comment: Yep, that’s an important detail. Not all fields support aggregation due to how their data is stored in the database. Roles do not exist in their own column, so you’d need a custom module to make this work.